# "..Save this password in your keychain.." and "...save this password in your icloud keychain" Messages are showing at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

I implemented to save password in iCloud.
I added associate domain in my project and added SecAddSharedWebCredential to save password after login successful.
But the problem is one of the iphone(XR, iOS 13) is showing two messages at the same time. One is save in your Keychain and another is in your iCloud Keychain.
All the iphones setting values of iCloud/autosavepassword/keychain are "On" .

How can I show only one message? If I remove SecAddSharedWebCredential , some of the iPhone did not show alert message anymore.

[image: attach image]